# I can't make the channel private

Tags: c#, discord.net

Well, I did so that the user could create a channel give it a name, a category where it will be located and roles that can join it, but I do not know how to make it private

```cs
public IPrivateChannel _privateChannel;

public async  Task PrivateChannels(string name, ulong categorychannel, IRole role) {
    OverwritePermissions permissions = new OverwritePermissions();
    var privateChannel = _privateChannel;
    var voiceChannel =  await Context.Guild.CreateVoiceChannelAsync(name, x => x.CategoryId = categorychannel);
    await voiceChannel.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(role, permissions);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to make private?

Comment: @hackerbuddy the channel that will be created when the user writes the command

Comment: Isn't that channel local to `PrivateChannels`?

Comment: @hackerbuddy I don't fully understand your question , but there are 2 types of voice channels in the discord, a General one that a user with a certain role can go to, and a private one that a user with a certain role can go to.I need a private channel.

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I misunderstood the `private` word with code base.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832919/discord-net-bot-create-a-private-channel is this the answer to your question?

Comment: @hackerbuddy I've already seen this question, but I couldn't get the channel to be private